# html5 video readystate random 2 or 4, video not loading

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm having some trouble with video on my website, hope there's somebody that can help.

There are 20 video's on a page, which i'm trying to play at the same time. For that i created a sort of a preloader which checks the readystate of the video.

For a test I've used 20 of the same video's with a unique id passed as get parameter so they are loaded separate.

Here's the html (this one is times 20):

```
    <video width="277" height="276"  class="bgvid" loop="loop">
        <source src="<?=DOMAIN?>video/big_buck_bunny.webm?cb=16" preload="auto" type="video/webm">
        <source src="<?=DOMAIN?>video/big_buck_bunny.mp4?cb=16" preload="auto" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

The javascript is as follows:

```
    function checkLoad(video, loaded) {
        console.log(video.readyState);
        if(video.readyState == 4) {
            loaded++;
        }
        return loaded;
    };



    function initVideo(){

        var count = $('.team').find('video.bgvid').length;
        var loaded = 1;
        var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
        var isLoaded = false;

        $.each(videos, $.proxy(function(i, elm) {
            console.log(loaded + ' == ' + count);
            if (loaded == count) {
                isLoaded = true;
                return false;
            } else {
                loaded = checkLoad(elm, loaded);
            }
        }, this));

        if (!isLoaded) {
            setTimeout(initVideo, 300);
        } else {
            $.each(videos,function() {
                this.play();
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem is that sometimes the readystate of the video is 2, when this happens the loader just keeps checking the readystate of the video. Sometimes it works allright. It seems to be completely random if it's 2 or 4. Is seems to be working better in firefox then in chrome.

What should I check / alter in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, I think you're asking a lot of your users' internet connections to load 20 videos concurrently...

Comment: Hi Psychemaster, you are right, but the video's are only 150 - 200 kb each. We'll add some loading animations later so that will be ok :) It's going to be a awesome webpage.

Comment: If you reduce the number of videos to a total of say, 4-6, does everything works consistently well? It may be a limitation of the number of open connections supported by the browser since you're trying to play all 20 simultaneously.

Comment: Hi Krg, thanks for the reply. I've tried it with 4 video's, but the same problem persists. The first video has a readystate 4 while the other videos have a readystate 2. I've downloaded the example mp4/webm from w3c (the big bunny movie), so the movie should be all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it out.

The video's didn't load well because of an autoplay attribute not being set.

Because of the source tags the video's are loaded all in one time, so I removed them and added them one by one if the previous video has a readystate of 4.

Thanks for the help!